# Hound: visible_text/1 returns an empty string

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to run an integration test with hound. 
The test looks like this:

```
defmodule RedBeardWeb.UserCanRegisterTest do
  use RedBeard.DataCase
  use ExUnit.Case
  use Hound.Helpers

  hound_session()

  ...

  name       = find_element(:class, "header__user_name")
  name_text  = visible_text(name)

  assert name_text   == "John D."
end
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
1) test user can register with valid credentials (MyAppWeb.UserCanRegisterTest)
   test/red_beard_web/integration/user_can_register_test.exs:30
   Assertion with == failed
   code:  assert name_text == "John D."
   left:  ""
   right: "John D."
   stacktrace: test/red_beard_web/integration/user_can_register_test.exs:39: (test)
```

visible_text/1 returns an empty string. When I perform all the actions in the test manually, the string is properly displayed.

[image: Mozilla inspector]

If I remove the element `.header__user_name` from the template and run the same test, I get the following error `** (Hound.NoSuchElementError) No element found for class 'header__user_name'`. So the element is found.

Why is `visble_text/1` returning an empty string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that text really visible, or is there some CSS that is hiding it?

What if you use `inner_text` instead of `visible_text`?

Comment: There's no CSS hiding the text, but using `inner_text/1` fixed the issue. Thanks